# could not reach in an if condition even when condition is true in a thread structure?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying something like whenever i press a button i want to reach inside of if condition (condition is a boolean variable) which is declared in an infitite loop. So the aim of the action listener method is making the boolean field `turnFlag` true then i can reach `System.out.println("Counter = " + counter);` statement in run time. However, when i press on button it never enters in `if(turnFlag)`, even the console prints out turnFlag as true. I cant understand why it doesnt enter in it ?. I will be appreciate if you can help.

```
public class ExampleController extends Thread implements Initializable {

    @FXML private static Button theButton;
    private int counter;
    private static boolean turnFlag=false;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        counter = 0;
        this.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){

        while(true){

            if(turnFlag){
                System.out.println("Counter = " + counter);
                turnFlag = false;
            }

        }
    }

    @FXML private void onAction(ActionEvent event){

        turnFlag=true;
        System.out.println("turnFlag = " + turnFlag);
    }
}
```

EDIT: i forgot to share Application class which is like

```
public class Example2 extends Application {

    public static Parent rootPane;  

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        rootPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("example.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: @JunedAhsan i always get only `turnFlag = true` after a pressed on the button. it never prints `Counter = ` part.

Comment: Are you sure, your thread has started? Can you try putting a sysout to confirm that?

Comment: Perhaps `turnFlag` needs to be `volatile`.

Comment: @JunedAhsan yeap i'm definitely sure that it starts.

Comment: @LouisWasserman i dont why but it works like a charm!. could you please explain it if you know ?

Comment: A change to a variable isn't guaranteed to propagate across threads unless that variable is `volatile`.

Comment: i got it :). So, i can accept your answer if you will write it.

Comment: BTW: Your code occupies the complete CPU while running because it has no sleep in it at all!

Comment: @tomsontom actually i considered that however, i'm implementing a turn based strategy game so whole game iterates in an infinite while loop and i decided not implement every player as a thread. There would be a time limit for each AI player but there will be not for human players. So they have to decide their actions via using shared GUI components. I had got stuck in implementing part of main game which based on pressing a button to end your turn. So as i said there will be only one thread which is "the main thread". If i used sleep i will got lost about controls over the components.